# How to pass InvokeDynamic as parameter to MethodCall in ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation

I want to generate byte code of a class which passes a method reference as argument to another method.
e.g.:

```
public class GeneratedClass {
    public GeneratedClass() {
        Test.foo((Function)Test::getId)
    }
}
```

Using ByteBuddy I can generate a class with custom constructor, and create an `InvokeDynamic` to represent the `Test::getId`, but the problem is that I cannot pass the `InvokeDynamic` as a parameter to my `MethodCall`. My current implementation is as follows:

```
var fooMethod = Test.class.getMethod("foo",Function.class);
InvokeDynamic methodRef = InvokeDynamic.lambda(Test.class.getMethod("getId"), Function.class)
        .withoutArguments();
new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(Object.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
        .name("GeneratedClass")
        .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
        .intercept(
                MethodCall.invoke(fooMethod)
                .with((Object)null) \\I want to pass the methodRef instead of null
                .andThen(methodRef)
        ).make()
        .saveIn(new File("target"));
```

Which generates the following:

```
public class GeneratedClass {
    public GeneratedClass() {
        Test.foo((Function)null);
        Test::getId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question, no documentation

Answer (score 2):

As of today, this is not supported by the DSL but you can supply a custom `StackManipulation` as an argument to `with`. In your case, you would need to resolve a `MethodInvocation` for this.

With a little trick, you can however implement this today but creating a helper method:

```
builder = builder
  .defineMethod("mylambda", Function.class, Visibility.PRIVATE, Ownership.STATIC)
  .intercept(methodRef)
```

You can then call this method using a `MethodCall` and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Reading the documentation, I cannot figure out how to do it using `StackManipulation`, Would you please produce a code example?